# Accessing an object in a class of a different django model

Tags: python, django, model

From this code

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter_name = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

Instead of using ForeignKey to get the entire class **Reporter** into **reporter_name**
I want to get just the first_name into reporter_name using ForeignKey, Im asking because the I want to use the class in a different model of another app.

Comment: You don't store the entire object. The `ForeignKey` itself will store the primary key of the object you refer to in the field.

Comment: Is there no way to get just the first_name in reporter_name even it its not with 'ForeignKey'. and I hope you understand what i mean, i want Reporter(first_name) only into reporter_name.

Comment: since it is not a `unique` field, no, since that means based on the `first_name` alone, you can not refer to a (unique) `Reporter`.

Comment: I think im supposed to use ManyToManyField

Answer (score 0):

If you are ONLY looking to store the name, you could do something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    def set_reporter_name(self, reporter_object):
        self.reporter_name = reporter_object.first_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

Then you would save it like so:

```
reporter = Reporter.objects.get(id=id)
article = Article.objects.create(headline=headline, pub_date=pub_date)
article.set_reporter_name(reporter)
article.save()
```

But in doing so, you lose access to the ForeignKey object when you query an Article, so all you will get is the name that was saved, not the Reporter object.

Alternatively, you could just create a function that returns the reporter_name from the ForeignKey, which is probably the better choice:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    def reporter_name(self):
       return self.reporter.first_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

Which would be accessed like:

```
article = Article.objects.get(id=id)
name = article.reporter_name()
```

Or in a template:

```
{% for article in articles.all %}
 <p>{{ article.headline }} Reported by: {{ article.reporter_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```